# System.Load fails other than Java\Bin

Tags: java, c++, jvm, interop, loadlibrary

I have a problem with System.load and System.loadLibrary of java (I tried both). I googled about them a lot but could find a solution for my exact problem. I have a java program that needs to call some .Net assemblies. For this reason, we built an application that includes interopability. This is the working flow, from left to right: Java – JNI – C++\CLI – C#

The problem is in my Java code. The program is running successfully when I copy all my dependent DLLs into Java installation folder (ProgramFiles\Java\bin). When running from Java\bin everything is fine, we reach to .Net assemblies. However, this is not an acceptable solution. Java\bin is for Java’s own binary files directory and we need to run it from another directory.
Here is the Java code portion:

```
static{
        System.out.print("Library(java.library.path):");
        System.out.print("\n GetProperty \n");
        System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.library.path"));
System.loadLibrary("AudioProcessingAgent");
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
        CsharpConsumer nc = new CsharpConsumer();
        nc.registerAssemblyHandler(".\\");
…
// Sample code of registerAssemblyHandler from this directory: http://codefry.blogspot.jp/2012/01/calling-net-dlls-from-java-code-without.html?m=1
}
```

I made sure that my directory is included in my PATH and in java.library.path
I found another workaround for the problem, in case I compile my java and convert my jar file into an Exe file this also would work fine from the path where the exe and the dlls located.  However, this is also not acceptable since we need to embed it into a java applet. Thus, I need to understand why system.load and system.loadLibrary fails out of java\bin. 
I got this error when I run it from out:

```
 # A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  Internal Error (0xe0434352), pid=10840, tid=9208
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (7.0_79-b15) (build 1.7.0_79-b15)

# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (24.79-b02 mixed mode, sharing windows-x86  )
# Problematic frame:
# C  [KERNELBASE.dll+0xc54f]
#
# Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client vers ions of Windows
```

I read about this error also. This is the reason why I added the function " registerAssemblyHandler" and it helped to run it from java\bin.

Comment: Do I correctly understand that you want to make use of native libraries in an applet that you plan to embed in a web page?  (Also, please do not include output as an image;  copy and paste the text directly into your question.)

Comment: yes, thats correct.

Comment: Are you loading this applet in a browser on a different computer?  If so, that computer would need to have the AudioProcessingAgent native library on its local file system.

Comment: it is the same client machine. We are loading the applet in IE in the same machine.

Comment: Your JVM crash appears to be due to a problem in your native library (such as a de-reference of a NULL pointer).  That aside, I see two problems:  First, applets normally do not have permission to load native libraries;  I don’t know if signing it will make a difference, and I don’t know if IE has special circumstances where it’s allowed, but I suspect it’s entirely up to the Java plug-in.  Second, `nc.registerAssemblyHandler(".\\")` is relying on the current directory, and the current directory could be anything when running in a browser, which means you should not rely on it.